# How to force a watch execution?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an Array of strings which I filter though an input. The value of this input is watched, and the new filtered Array is created upon changes in the input value. This works fine.

Independently of this I have a switch toggle which changes the way the filtering works, by modifying the function in the watch.

**My problem: toggling this switch is not taken into account until the moment the input changes again.** This is normal and expected: the watched value did not change.

Is there a way to :

- either force the execution of a `watch` function (in which case I would also watch the toggle)
- or use an `OR` construction in the watch ("if either the input or the toggle change, do this and that...")

What do right now is to have one extra `method` that does the filtering, that is called on the input or slider change. This works but I am wondering whether there is a better way to cleverly slim down the code.

Comment: What about set `new filtered Array` as a `computed` property of the component that is computed from the `toggle` and `input`

Comment: @dothuan: excellent idea, thanks! Would you mind please turning that into an answer?

Comment: There are answers that has same idea as mine, so i won't make a new answer. Would you mind upvote my comment?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `computed` property to return filtered Array. No need to use `watch`. Computed properties are just for that occasions

If you want to use `watch`:

1. create a `method` that does the filtering.
2. Fire this `method` in a `watcher`
3. Fire it when `toggle` change.

Two working solutions, but computed would work better.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should use a `computed` property instead of `watch` in this case.

```
computed: {
    computedArray() {
        let result = [];

        // your filtering code that include switch toggle

        return result;
    }
}
```